# Create a new branch and move commits after head to new branch and sync with GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm not sure if I screwed this up or not. I had a local repository that looked like this with a detached head:

[image]

I'm attempting to split off a devel branch from the v0.03 tag and have the pscott-au branch split off from the devel branch.

So I did:

```
git checkout master (moved head back to tip)
git branch devel
git reset --hard 0060 (this is where the HEAD was in the picture at v0.03)
git co devel
git co master
```

So now I have a repo that looks like this:

[image]

I want to move the pscott-au so it branches off of devel. And then I want to sync up these changes to GitHub. I'm a little lost as to how to proceed because I'm not sure if I screwed the first part of this up or not.

Comment: Checkout only moves the HEAD, so you cannot possibly have changed from the first diagram to the second using only those commands.

Comment: Straight from command history: `8365  git co 0060
 8366  git tag -a v0.03
 8367  git branch devel
 8368  git branch -d devel
 8369  git branch --help
 8370  git co master
 8371  ls
 8372  git branch devel
 8373  git reset --hard 0060
 8374  git co devel
 8375  git co master`

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `origin/master` shown twice in the second image, but that's probably what is throwing off @Miral. (I see it's shown twice in the first image too, but at least there, both copies point to the same commit...)

Comment: I think it's probably because the GitHub repo doesn't have devel on it yet. Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, `pscott-au` *already* branches off `devel`.  It also branches off `master`.  Well, inasmuch as it branches off anything, which is to say, not at all. :-)

The fact is that branch names simply act as pointers to commits.  The commits are the round circles in your diagrams.

Commits never change or move; their connections never change or move.  (You can draw them in / drag them around to different places, but their connections get dragged along with them in that case, so even if the drawing *looks* different, it represents the same graph.)

The branch *names*, on the other hand, move all the time.  A branch name just remembers *one specific commit*, which Git calls the *tip of the branch*.  A commit can be the tip of a branch one moment, then somewhere deep in the branch, or not contained in the branch at all, at the next moment.  That's what happened when you moved the name `master` back so that it pointed to the commit now labeled `v0.03` as well.

What makes a branch name *be* a branch name is ... well, in reality, it's the fact that its internal spelling is `refs/heads/name`, but the key *feature* of a branch name is that you can run `git checkout name` and then run various things ending with `git commit`.  The commit command makes a *new* commit—a new round node on the graph—whose parent connection goes back to the commit you checked-out earlier; and then, at the end of the `git commit` process, Git adjusts the *name* so that it points to the new commit you just made!

The various `origin/*` names are your local Git's way of remembering where the branch names in the *other* Git repository, stored on GitHub, were the last time your local Git called up the GitHub Git.  You get them from the other Git using `git fetch`.  You ask or tell the other Git to *change* them using `git push`, as in `git push flags origin name1 name2 ...`.  They will obey a request if the change you are suggesting is a *fast-forward* operation.  The *`flags`* can include `--force` to make it a command instead of a polite request (though they can still disobey commands); that—or some variant of that, such as `--force-with-lease`—is required if the change you want to make is *not* a fast-forward.

The change you want here is not a fast-forward, so you will need to run `git push --force origin devel master`.  That will send them any new commits you have that they don't—which is none, so that's really fast—and then command them to set their `devel` to one of those commits (which they would do even as a request) and command them to set their `master` to another (which they will obey if you're the administrator of that repository or otherwise authorized per whatever rules you've told GitHub to enforce).

Once your Git knows that their Git has accepted this new-name-creation and `master`-name-change, your Git will add `origin/devel` to your remote-tracking names, and move your `origin/master` to remember the commit that they agreed to use for their `master`.

Comment: OK, the `git push` command you recommended got rid of some warnings I was getting.

So basically, I'm done. When the time comes, I'll merge in the pscott-au into devel.

Answer (score 1):

You've performed a hard reset on `master` to move it back earlier than `origin/master` (ignoring `>origin/master`; I don't know what that is but it's weird).

This is a bad idea in general, as it rewrites history and will be rejected by default.  You can override that with a forced push if it really is intended, but it will likely annoy anyone else using the same repository.  Fortunately in this specific case the commits will not actually be lost as long as you also push the devel branch (but loss is possible in other cases if you're not careful).

To answer your direct question: to move the two additional commits on the pscott-au branch to the devel branch, you can execute the following sequence:

```
git co pscott-au
git rebase devel
```

This *also* counts as a history rewrite, so will need to be force-pushed to Github.  If you are **very very sure** that this is what you wanted, you can do this with:

```
git push origin devel
git push -f origin master pscott-au
```

Comment: I *think* everything is looking good right now: https://github.com/sdondley/moo-google after doing @torek's suggested command.

I'm not sure why I need to do a rebase (sorry, just read a book on git like two weeks ago and barely knew how to use it before that). Won't my next step be just to do a simple merge of the pscott-au branch into the devel branch periodically?

Comment: Rebase vs merge is one of those religious debates that has no right answer.  It really depends on what you're trying to do and what you want the history graph to look like afterwards.

Comment: My answer assumes that there was one commit at the tip of `devel` which was not present in `pscott-au`, and that you wanted to make the latter branch look like it it was branched off that current commit instead of where it previously branched off from.  A rebase will do that (at the cost of changing history).  A merge will put a fork in the graph.  In both cases you will end up with pscott-au containing all three commits, but how you get there differs, as does what the graph looks like afterwards.  (As a general rule, merging is safer but uglier.)

Comment: OK, for whatever reason I was thinking `rebase` would get rid of the pscott-au branch. I gotta review the book. Quick bit of advice while I have you. Should I have the contributors do a series of commits on their same branch or should I ask them to put each different/distinct change on a separate branch from their main developer branch? I'm leaning toward the latter but don't know if that's a hassle. They'll be able to create their own branches on the fly, right?

Comment: Rebase will *sort of* get rid of the branch.  What it does is it creates a **new** branch called pscott-au which branches off from the chosen point (devel) and includes copies of the commits on the original branch.  Now origin/pscott-au and pscott-au point to unrelated places, which is why the forced push is needed to tell GitHub to throw away the "old" branch and use the "new" one instead.

Comment: For your other question, you should read up about feature branches. You can either have direct contributors create separate feature branches, commit as desired, then finally merge to the devel branch.  Or they can create branches, commit as desired, then finally rebase (and optionally squash) onto the devel branch.  Which one is "better" depends on what you want the graph to look like.  (And the final graph is identical for create-branch-then-rebase-and-squash vs. just-commit-directly-on-devel, so if that's the way you go then you don't need to care what they do.)

Comment: It sounds like in general you should probably read up on different git workflows and choose the one you like the best.  "git flow" is a relatively popular one, although I personally dislike it; I prefer something closer to [OneFlow](https://www.endoflineblog.com/oneflow-a-git-branching-model-and-workflow), although not completely identical.

Comment: I've done a little reading but it's all so confusing until you actually do it. I want to be able to allow the developers to do their own thing but I want to be sure I can thoroughly review the commits before adding them to devel branch.

Comment: If you want full review control, then you don't give contributors push access, you get them to create pull requests (PRs) instead.

Comment: OK, yeah, that's the way it's set up now, I guess by default. Thanks.